# How to build Objective-c++ code using GCC or Clang?

Tags: c++, objective-c, gcc, clang, objective-c++

I have a complete knowledge about C++ and a little bit about Objective-C
So please tell me how to write and compile in Objective-C++ code

1) Writing Code

2) Compiling with GCC or Clang(Commands)(Tell me for GCC, if its possible)

3) Which .extension i should write to save Objective-C++

4) Can i use this in Qt Creator

5) Good Book or site to learn Objective-C++

Comment: "Compile with minGW or clang" - minGW is not a compiler.

Comment: I know  its basically a GCC compiler that minGW provides. I request to you , if you can tell me how to do it

Comment: Yeah. Googled "how to use GCC"? Same options apply to clang (mostly).

Comment: I searched but it was very confusing

Comment: Probably it was just English... Anyway, `gcc -o prog -Wall SourceFile.mm -lfoo` etc. should work.

Comment: Thanks H2CO3(Carbonic Acid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Its most common to use xcode as an IDE.
2. The latest xcode version does use CLang as its default compiler. 
   MinGw is a compiler for windows, so you would have to use something like GnuStep on windows to run objective c code http://www.gnustep.org/.
3. The Objective-C++ extension is ".mm"
4. i dont think so.
5. The apple developer sites.